# insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Trying to save a post on a django project I got this error

*The above exception (insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user". ) was the direct cause of the following exception:*

The model:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The view:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .models import Post


class BlogView(ListView):
    template_name = 'base/blog.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 2


class PostView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'base/post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']

        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk, slug=slug)
        context['post'] = post
        return context
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Kevin, it seems like the user id is invalid or may be the user has been deleted. Please check if its a valid user id.

Answer (score 4):

That because the ***django_admin_log*** table still contains a foreign key relation to the old ***auth_user*** table.

You need to drop this and recreate the table.

```
psql => DROP table django_admin_log;
```

For Django >= 1.7

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001 | ./manage.py dbshell
```

And that's it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply work like a charm when you have psql installed

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat**! You should use that approach for the tables you are not afraid to lose the data for and understand on 100% what you are doing, otherwise that's dangerous and may encounter data loss.

**Caveat 2**. You may encounter multiple apps with such issue. If you are not ready to lose the data make a dump for those apps / tables, follow the instructions underneath, and then upload the dumped data.

Migrate the problematic apps to zero

> `python manage.py migrate admin zero`

And the Run migrations again

> python manage.py migrate admin

P.S. If that's a custom apps then you may want to fake rollback only few migrations instead of initials.